# knockout.js data-binding cannot have template and value together

Tags: html, knockout.js

I tried to use template on `<select>` control but it does not work. Here is the code that doesn't work.

```
<select data-bind="template: { name: 'os-template-detail', foreach: operatingSystems },
        value: selectedOperatingSystem"></select>
```

But when I use normal binding it works well.

```
<select data-bind="options: operatingSystems,
        optionsText: function (item) {
            return item.Name
        },
        value: selectedOperatingSystem"></select>
```

So, I want to know if I do anything wrong or it's just the limitation of the framework.

**Update**
Both of them show list of operating system. The problem is when I select an os on the first combobox it does not update its source while the second cobobox updates its source.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to specify how the `operatingSystems` list and your `os-template-detail` should be composed to an `option` element. The problem with your binding is that knockout tries to make a list of `<select>` tag instead of `option` tag.

This might work:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: operatingSystems">
    <option data-bind="template: {name: 'os-template-detail', data: $data}">
</select>
```

Also I recommend to use `Durandal`'s composition instead of knockout templates. [This link](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/) describes how to integrated your knockout with durandal.

Comment: I added more info to my question. The problem is data not update after I select an item on the CoboBox not when loading data into it.

Comment: @Anonymous Have you checked the generated DOM? I think in the first case, the `<select>` DOM will consist of `div`s instead of `option`s. So selecting something wouldn't raise any meaningful event to select.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it and it's correct. <select data-bind="template: { name: 'os-template-detail', foreach: operatingSystems },
     value: selectedOperatingSystem">
  <option data-bind="text: Name" class="body-text">Windows 2012 - Application Server</option>
 
  <option data-bind="text: Name" class="body-text">Windows 2012 - Database Server</option>
 </select>